# The background images don't cover the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, slider

In image rotator js, the tag background-size don't work, images don't cover the entire div... Someone can help me?

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

 var imgArr = new Array( // relative paths of images
 'imgs/contact/01.png',
 'imgs/contact/03.png',
 'imgs/contact/02.jpg'
 );

 var preloadArr = new Array();
 var i;

 /* preload images */
 for(i=0; i < imgArr.length; i++){
 preloadArr[i] = new Image();
 preloadArr[i].src = imgArr[i];
 }

 var currImg = 1;
 var intID = setInterval(changeImg, 6000);

 /* image rotator */
 function changeImg(){
 $('#contact #banner').animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function(){
 $(this).css('background','url(' + preloadArr[currImg++%preloadArr.length].src +') top center no-repeat','background-attachment', 'fixed','background-size','cover');
 }).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000);
 }

 });
</script>
```

I don't know if the css on js is well done, written right...

the html:

```
<div id="contact">
    <div id="banner" style="background-size: cover;"></div>
</div>
```

the css:

```
#contact {
            background: #fff;
            width: 100%;
            height: 950px;
        }
#contact #banner {
            background: url('imgs/contact/01.png') center center no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position-y: 40%;
            width: 100%; height: 500px; margin-top: -50px;
        }
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/87z5p17e/**

Comment: Please, Post your html

Comment: posted the html section

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle because your images doesn't have an absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `height:100%;` to the `#banner` element because the `#banner` has `height: 500px;` which is smaller than its parent(`#contact height:950px;`).

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/87z5p17e/1/)

```
#contact #banner {
    background: url('http://www.barrymellorphotography.co.uk/assets/Uploads/landscapes-13.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: 40%;
    width: 100%;
    // height: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: but the `background-size:cover;` makes the image cover the div in any heigh size, the first img, on css is working perfect, and the other images that I added through js not work with this  `background-size:cover;`

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't get you. Can you explain more?

Comment: the first image, in css, is working fit on 500pxdiv, the other 3 images over the js, don't fit in 500pxdiv, the `background-size:cover` don't make any effect in this 3 images, understand?

Comment: [I fixed it](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/87z5p17e/2/). You had jquery a mistake. You tried to pass several css properties to the [css() method](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties) without curly bracket. I suggest you to add these style in your style sheet instead of using jquery

Comment: Ow nice one! this will really helpful, thank u so much!